# Renaming a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, file-rename, randomaccessfile

i have a RAF called data.bin and a temporary RAF called temp.bin.

```
        data = new RandomAccessFile("data.bin","rws");
        temp = new RandomAccessFile("temp.bin","rws");
```

the temp file is basically the data.bin file but i alter the information in it. so once im done altering the temp file how do i change the name of temp.bin to data.bin and delete the old data.bin?

ive seen some things about renaming Files with .renameTo() and stuff but that does apply to a RandomAccessFile. and i couldnt find any method like that for RAFs

Answer (score 1):

RandomAccessFile was not designed to replace the File class.

It was designed to allow reading an writing only well more or less.

Please use the File class to do the renaming.

Comment: so to do that i just do?            File fdata = new File("data.bin");
File ftemp = new File("temp.bin");
ftemp.renameTo(fdata);
ftemp.delete();

Comment: If you rename it no need to delete I think.

Answer (score 1):

Close RAF and use java.nio.file.Files.move to rename the temp file. File.renameTo has a draw back. If it fails to rename the file you will never know why since it just returns true or false. Files.move throws IOException if fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
I did something like this:

```
data.close();
temp.close();
File tempfile = new File("c:/.../temp.bin");
File datafile = new File("c:/.../data.bin");
tempfile.renameTo(datafile);
```

For more information: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_renameto.htm

Comment: Do you need to delete the data-file, before renaming 'temp' onto it?

Comment: I don't think so, but this code just stopped working here .-.
I'm cofuse now. It says that the file isn't closed, but I closed with the data.close() and the temp.close()...

I tried to close the channel, but didn't have any change.
Now I need help with that too kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

RandomAccessFile purpose is to read/write information. To handle file names, existence, etc., you must use the File class.

In your case, you should do something like this:

```
File d = new File("data"); // Declare your data RAF through File
RandomAccessFile data = new RandomAccessFile(d,"rws");

public void foo(){
    File t = new File("temp"); // Declare your temp RAF through File
    RandomAccessFile temp = new RandomAccessFile(t,"rws");
    //TODO data RAF alteration
    data.close();
    d.delete(); //First delete data File, just in case
    temp.close();
    File f = new File("data");
    t.renameTo(f);
}
```